# Is the free product contained in amalgamated product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-product

I'm trying to understand the subgroups of finite index of amalgamated products in some particular cases and it arises the following question:

> Suppose that $G = A \ast_C B$ where $A$ and $B$ are finite groups. If $A_1 \leq A$ and $B_1 \leq B$, then is true that $A_1 \ast B_1 \leq A \ast_C B$?

I'm not sure if this is true. Because perhaps we can be $G$ being soluble and $A_1 \ast B_1$ not soluble, but this is only intuition.

Comment: Your question is unclear as written. The groups $A_1, B_1$ are naturally embedded in $G=A*_CB$. Are you asking if these subgroups generate a free product as a subgroup of $G$? Or, are you asking if a free product $A_1* B_1$ admits an embedding as a subgroup if $G$? Or, something else?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I want to know if $A_1 \ast B_1$ generates an isomorphic copy as a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Then the answer is "sometimes yes, sometimes not."

Comment: @MoisheKohan is there some conditions ensuring that it occurs or it is "ramdom"?

Comment: It is a free product provided that $A_1\cap C=\{1\}, B_1\cap C=\{1\}$ (finiteness of $A, B$ are irrelevant here). Proofs that I know are not algebraic but use either topology or group actions on trees. It does not mean, of course, that there is no purely algebraic argument.

Comment: If you know the normal forms for the amalgamated product, it can be proven algebraically (in the situation mentioned by Moishe Kohan) by selecting a family of coset representatives of $C$ in $A$ that include all elements of $A_1$, and in $A$ including all elements of $B_1$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, take $A_1=A$, $B_1=B$ and recall that the pushout (aka amalgam) is a quotient of the coproduct (aka free product) of groups. It doesn't make sense to regard the pushout as an subobject of the coproduct.